# React Redux Immutable state not being returned

Tags: redux, immutable.js

I'm learning redux and immutables and doing a todo app.

when i trigger the ADD_ITEM action i get "state.push is not a function"

If i change this line

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
```

to

`const reducer = (state =  new List(), action) => {`

i can add new items but the inital ones don't show, how can fix this?

```
export const initialState =  Map({
  items: List (
      Map({ id: 1, content: 'Call mum' }),
      Map({ id: 2, content: 'Buy cat food' }),
      Map({ id: 3, content: 'Water the plants' })
  )
});

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log("action.type", action.type);
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ITEM:
      return state.push(Map({
        id: nextId++,
        content: action.content
      }));
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

state is not an instance of Array and therefore will not have access to the Array.push() method.  State is an object.

Firstly I'd avoid using any mutating method, e.g. push(), within your reducer itself.  It's better to keep those defined within your actions -- if you must use them.

I don't see the utility of "List" or "Map" in this example.  To be literal-minded:

```
const initialState = {
  items: [
           {id: 1, content: 'call mum'},
           {id: 2, content: 'call dad'},
  ],
}
```

Within your reducer itself, I highly recommend an immutable method like object rest spread.

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case "ADD_ITEM": 
      return {...state, items: [...state.items, action.newItem]}
  }

  ...
}
```

If you want to feed your initial state, you can then set another case in your reducer as follows:

```
 switch(action.type){
    case "ADD_ITEM": 
      return {...state, items: [...state.items, action.newItem]}
    case "SET_NEW_LIST":
      return {...state, items: action.newList}
    ...
  }
```

And define another action accordingly.  More or less, Dan Abramov and others encourage keeping your reducers as simpler as possible and keeping the logic within your actions as much as possible.  Your id incrementation should be taken care of within your ADD_ITEM action.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I wanted to use immutablejs like in https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-a-todo-app-using-react-redux-and-immutable-js/ which I’m loosely following. The above is only a snippet of the test app I’m building. Will be further functionality to toggle, remove, filter the state.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to restructure your initial state like that :

```
export const initialState =  List ([
  Map({ id: 1, content: 'Call mum' }),
  Map({ id: 2, content: 'Buy cat food' }),
  Map({ id: 3, content: 'Water the plants' })
])
```

If you want to keep a more complexe structure like `Map{ items: List }` you have to refactor your reducer and your state :

```
export const initialState =  Map({
  items: List ([
  //           ^ don't forget the brackets here
      Map({ id: 1, content: 'Call mum' }),
      Map({ id: 2, content: 'Buy cat food' }),
      Map({ id: 3, content: 'Water the plants' })
  ])
});

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ITEM:
      return state.set('items', state.get('items').push(
        Map({
          id: nextId++,
          content: action.content
        })
      ));
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```